# Convert numbers in thousands separator into float

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, locale

I'm new for programming language, so I keep get struggling with simple converting and calculation progress. Can you guys please advise what's the problem and how to solve it? 
 My data is consisted of various columns with thousand separator, which can't be used to calculating. Since I'd like to mutate new column using old ones calculation, I tried to let the string columns be a float.

I've tried replace(',','') and also the locale but sadly it didn't work. 
Below is the some piece of my DataFrame.

```
Columns:
Title
Month
Country
Screens
Seats
Admission
Local_Currency
Units_per_USD

Index: 0
A 1 Z 77 6,468 2,053 482,455.00 17.126106 

Index: 1
B 2 Y 78 6,552 903 212,205.00 17.126106 

Index: 2    
C 1 X 52 4,368 1,054 247,150.00 17.126106
```

Goal: Divide Local_Currency by Units_per_USD, draw a new column for USD_Currency 
Steps that I thought should be ahead: convert numbers with thousands separator columns into int, float so that it's available to adapt arithmatic operation.

```
s = df['Bo_local']
s = pd.to_numeric(s)

ValueError: Unable to parse string "482,455.00" at position 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to just remove the commas, then call `float`.

```
>>> s = '123,456.78'
>>> float(s.replace(',',''))
123456.78
```

In your case, you'll want `pandas.map`:

```
data[column] = data[column].map(lambda s: s.replace(',',''))
```

This will apply the function to every value in the column.

Comment: Awesome the second code works. Thank you so much for your help.